# Kohana: Ajax Request Error

Tags: php, ajax, routes, kohana

I have this code in my `bootstrap.php`

```
Route::set('get_locations','ajax/locations.json')
    ->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'ajax',
    'action'     => 'locations',
  ));
```

And this is the code in my `Ajax.php`

```
public function locations(){
  echo json_encode(array("success" => true));
}
```

I can't seem to make it work when I make an ajax call like the one below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "ajax/locations.json",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result){
      if(result["success"]=='true'){
        alert('success');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The request always returns `404 Not Found`

Any help will do.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried accessing the URL directly via browser? Also, if it's Kohana 3.3 you might want to make sure the class, controller and file name case is exactly the same - your file is called `Ajax.php` but the controller in route is `ajax`, so there's an inconsistency here.

Comment: I have tried to change the cases of the controller name but to no avail. The request still returns 404. Also, I tried accessing it through url but same result, 404 error page.

Answer (score 2):

You action function is incorrectly named. It currently is:

```
public function locations(){
```

Should be:

```
public function action_locations(){
//              ^^^^^^^
```

Note the `action_` prefix. It is required for all action methods.

Comment: Thanks for that. I missed out the prefix for the method. I changed it, but still the ajax request doesn't work same with accessing the action through the url. I am totally lost on what's wrong.

Comment: Interesting... Have you changed the route default controller to `Ajax` (first letter uppercase to be consistent with file name and class name)?

Comment: Try escaping the dot in the route: `Route::set('get_locations','ajax/locations\.json')`. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the regexp without a . in it. Change your route to:

```
Route::set('get_locations','ajax/locations')
```

without (json extension) and prefix your controller name with "action_":

```
public function action_locations()
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it!

I just added `.htaccess` file in the root directory of my project!

That solved the problem.

Thanks for all the answers guys.